# Displaying JSON data into a pie chart using chart.js

Tags: json, ajax, charts, chart.js

my first time using chart.js and am running into a small bug that I can't seem to work around it. Below is my code, however, its just displaying the labels but not rendering the pie chart itself.

Am following samples from the chart.js documentation here http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart-example-usage

Your help will be appreciated.

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="200" height="200"></canvas>

 $(document).ready(function () {
 /*
         -> #47A508 = green (wins)
         -> #ff6a00 = orange (losses)
         -> #ffd800 = yellow (draws)
    */
    var DataArray = [];
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/426/leagueTable',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
    }).done(function (result) {
        $.each(result.standing, function () {
            var name = "Manchester United FC";
            if (this.teamName == name) {
                DataArray.push([this.wins, this.losses, this.draws]);
            }
        });
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'pie',
            data: {
                label: 'Manchester United Current Form',
                labels: [
                        "Wins",
                        "Losses",
                        "Draws"
                ],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        data: DataArray,
                        backgroundColor: [
                            "#47A508",
                            "#ff6a00",
                            "#ffd800"
                        ],
                        hoverBackgroundColor: [
                            "#FF6384",
                            "#36A2EB",
                            "#FFCE56"
                        ]
                    }]
            },
            options: { responsive: true }
        });
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this solved, well sadly, with no magic at all to brag about. There was nothing wrong with the code initially, however, it was a problem with the DOM rendering performance. Thank you @alwaysVBNET and @Aniko Litvanyi for your inputs as well.

This [link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/analyzing-crp)  helped me out, hopefully it does to someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is because of the jquery each, it fills DataArray async and the array is not ready, when you want to use it as chart data. 
Change the $.each to a simple js for loop

```
for(var i = 0; i < result.standing; i++){
   var name = "Manchester United FC";
   var team = result.standing[i];
       if (team.teamName == name) {
          DataArray.push(team.wins, team.losses, team.draws);
       }
}
```

Comment: I just tried this but the chart is still not rendering. If possible, can you provide a working jsfiddle for this. Thanks.

Comment: Are there any error messages on the dev toolbar console?

Comment: The few errors i was seeing were part from some rss feeds am trying to add to my page, but not related to the chart. I've since cleaned those up, but its still not rendering. The canvas is taking up the space (width&height) i allocated it, but its just not showing the pie chart itself.

Comment: I edited my answer above, check the push part. The data must be an array of numbers, but previously (and in your code) it was an array of arrays.

Comment: Seems to be an error with pushing the json data into the array. I tried your solution, but with both $.each and the for loop, the data is being pushed into the array when i run a debugger onto the browser console.

Comment: I changed my code to look like this below - but its still not working.
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/426/leagueTable',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
    }).done(function (result) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.standing; i++) {
            var name = "Manchester United FC";
            var team = result.standing[i];
            if (team.teamName == name) {
                DataArray.push(team.wins, team.losses, team.draws);
            }
        }

/*rest of code above*/

Answer (score 0):

try `callbacks` for you ajax or do the below (which is a dirty solution):

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/426/leagueTable',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false, //add this
        async: false, //add this
        type: 'GET',
```

Also
   the result of your ajax could be returned using the below code instead of using an array.

```
jQuery.parseJSON(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in your DataArray. The way it is implemented is is an array with a single entry. Which is another array itself.

```
[[<wins>, <losses>, <draws>]]
```

instead of

```
[<wins>, <losses>, <draws>]
```

That is because you instantiate an array and then push into it an array object.

To fix this try using the following function:

```
(...)
$.each(result.standing, function () {
    var name = "Manchester United FC";
    if (this.teamName == name) {
        DataArray = ([this.wins, this.losses, this.draws]);
        console.log("This team name");
    }
});
(...)
```